# Помогите с генератором карты в pygame python

Tags: python, pygame

я делаю генератор 2д карты в pygame. Написал вот такой класс:

```
import pygame as pg
import config

class Wordl:
    def __init__(self):
        with open('map.txt') as file:
            self.place = file.read().splitlines()

    def generate_place(self, sc):
        for string in self.place:
            for i in range(0, len(string)):
                if string[i] == '#':
                    pg.draw.rect(sc, config.WHITE, (50 * i, 50 * self.place.index(string), 50, 50))
                if string[i] == '.':
                    pass
```

файл map.txt:

```
##########
#........#
#........#
#........#
#........#
#........#
#........#
##########
```

Но, почему-то не прорисовывается нижняя часть карты:
[image: не прорисовывается нижняя часть карты]

основной файл game.py (запускает игру):

```
import pygame as pg

from player import Player
from wordl import Wordl
import config

pg.init()
pg.mixer.init()

sc = pg.display.set_mode((config.WIDTH, config.HEIGHT))
time = pg.time.Clock()
player = Player()
wordl = Wordl()
wordl.__init__()

while 1:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            exit()

    sc.fill(config.BLACK)

    pg.draw.circle(sc, config.GREEN, (player.get_pos()), 10)
    player.movemoment() # перемещение игрока
    player.lines(sc)

    wordl.generate_place(sc)

    pg.display.flip() # обновление дисплея
    time.tick(config.FPS) # установка тикрейта
```

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью словаря вместо списка